# if i click button, change my human texture. How can i do?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3dsmax

I need code and guidance. I have one button and a human model. I created the human and two textures, but my code doesn't changed the human's texture.

```
public Sprite myImage;
public Button kirmizi;
void Start()
{

    myImage = Resources.Load<Sprite>("SportyGrilSkin1.png"); // Make sure not to include the file extension

    //Make sure it is added in the Inspector. Or reference it using GameObject.Find.
    kirmizi.image.sprite = myImage; // That is right, no need to GetComponent.

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}
```

Comment: As the answer points out you're putting the sprite on the button and not any model but it may also be worth pointing out that your filename has a typo in it. This won't affect functionality if the actual filename has the same typo but in case it's different thought it worth pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

```
kirmizi.image.sprite = myImage;
```

It means put `myImage` to button sprite.

I think you should put `myImage` to `human`'s sprite.

```
    public Sprite myImage;
    public Sprite humanImage;
    public SpriteRenderer humanSpriteRenderer;

    void Start()
    {
        myImage = Resources.Load<Sprite>("SportyGrilSkin1.png"); // Make sure not to include the file extension
        humanSpriteRenderer=GameObject.Find("human").GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        humanImage = GameObject.Find("human").GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite; // you need 'human' object. it has sprite.
    }

    void OnClick() {
          humanSpriteRenderer.sprite=myImage;
        //humanImage = myImage;

    }
```

About `OnClick()`, It is callback function from Button component.

If you don't understand about it, Check out this page.

[UI Button OnClick Function](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/974622/unity-502f1-ui-button-onclick-function.html)